# error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files

Tags: git

у меня есть две ветки, я смерджила с локальной ветки devM в ветку локальную test .потом я хочу запулить на локальную ветку test запулить с ветки репозитория и у меня вылезает эта ошибка...

```
>git pull origin test
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

коммит файлов меня не спас... Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Что выдаёт *git status —ignored*? Если там не пусто, *git clean -xdf* может помочь (удаляет весь мусор из репозитория). Либо *git add ...; git commit -a -s*.

Comment: @0andriy спасибо!!!!